# How to pass parameters in AngulrJs through $stateProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to pass an id parameter from URL to controller.

here it is my config file

```
$stateProvider.state('main.edit_tutor', {
        url : '/home/edit/:id', // here I want to pass Id
        views:{
            "header":{ templateUrl : 'templates/header.html',
                    controller : 'HeaderController',
            },
            "sidebar":{ templateUrl : 'templates/sidebar.html',
                        controller:'SidebarController',
            },
            "main":{ templateUrl : 'templates/editTutor.html',
                    controller:'TutorEditController',
            },
            "footer":{ templateUrl : 'templates/footer.html',
            },

        }
      })
```

I want that id param in `TutorEditController`

```
    app.controller('TutorEditController', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $state, LoginService,FetchService,UtilityService,$filter,UpdateService,$routeParams) { 

    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;

});
```

I tried passing id like this

```
http://localhost/tutor_crm/#/main/home/edit?id=4
http://localhost/tutor_crm/#/main/home/edit/id=4
http://localhost/tutor_crm/#/main/home/edit/4
```

I am getting error like `Error: [$injector:unpr]`

Comment: use `$stateParams` not `$routeParams`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are injecting `routeParams` which is for `ngRoute`, but you used `angular-ui-router`

Since you are using `angular-ui-router` you should use **`$stateParams`** not **`$routeParams`**

```
app.controller('TutorEditController', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $state, LoginService,FetchService,UtilityService,$filter,UpdateService) { 
    $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
});
```

The URL should be,

**`http://localhost/tutor_crm/#/main/home/edit/4`**

Comment: glad to help you. you can accept my answer, if you find it useful. :)